# Can I plumb this restaurant sink this way?

Tags: sink, cpvc

Came across a 3 basin restaurant style sink that I am going to use in my basement (homebrewing!).

I'm using CPVC to connect to this faucet but there was originally a short threaded black pipe nipple with washers that went into the faucet from the back side and then a female CPVC connection to the water supply. The black nipples were solid gunk & rust inside so I removed them.

Instead of going back with another black pipe connection, can I not just use  CPVC male adapters straight into the back of the faucet?..is CPVC strong enough to make this connection and hold the faucet to the sink? It seems to hold (see pictures) but I didn't tighten it down very far, only did this as a test.  It seems like there should be a locknut on the back side to hold the 
faucet in place and then the threaded plumbing fitting, but no one at the home center could help me find anything like this...should there be one?

[image: IMG_6765.jpg]
[image: IMG_6763.jpg]
[image: IMG_6760.jpg]

Comment: You can get brass nipples at Home Depot. I would not trust plastic to make a mechanical connection to hold the faucet to the sink. You are setting up the conditions for a flood.  But you are planning for the same threads to do double duty--seal the connection and clamp the faucet body to the sink. You need a separate nut to clamp. Some other system is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this done with bad results due to the weight and abuse a large fixture goes thru with accidentally knocking pots and pans into it. My suggestion would be to use galvanized pipes not black pipes those are for gas lines but I have seen it many times.  The size of galvanized pipe usually in such small size is fully threaded so get one a little longer than needed and add a large pan washer to distribute weight and add a galvanized thin walled nut to add support then add 2 brass angled pex quick connects at 3/4 inch and pex it to your existing pipes with appropriate push in addapters.  This will give strength to the faucets structure and add a way to quick disconnet the bench from the wall if need to be moved or cleaned behind. Just a few ways  I did mine and with casters i can load it onto the lowboy trailer and travel with the shop.☺ Have fun!

Comment: By "thin walled nut" do you mean a "jam nut"?  I can't find anything called a thin walled nut... and will nuts & bolts aisle nuts match the threads on a galvanized pipe nipple?

Comment: Yes sir but you could also use a conduit nut from the electrical section or 2

Comment: Here is a link https://www.amazon.com/Pipe-Fittings-Locknut/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A383612011%2Cp_n_feature_four_browse-bin%3A3052055011

Comment: Upgrade and use brass nipples. I didn't think anyone used galvanized water pipes anymore.